# Azure DB connection issue via SSMS SQL Server error 64

Tags: sql, database, azure, ssms

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 64)

No changes done, all of a sudden not able to connect.

Only change I could see is my net speed keeps toggling btw Mbps - Kbps

Comment: Did it just start happening today?  Was it working yesterday?  Azure is having issues with their MFA today: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/

Comment: it was working well before. seems momentary. Able to connect now